# Is there an algebra for this numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to split complex numbers into 3 components:

$Z=(x,y)=x+i \cdot y = (a,b,c)$

$Z \in \mathbb{C}; a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$

this way

$c= x \: bitwiseAND \: y \\
a=x-c \\
b=y-c$

I need an algebra of numbers $(a,b,c)=(x-x\wedge y, y-x\wedge y,x\wedge y)$, where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\wedge$ is the bitwise AND binary operator.

I have a hard time doing products and powers, because the AND doesn't distribute with addition, and I need to express $(a,b,c)$ in terms of $(a,b,c)$, and not as functions of $(x,y)$

As consequence of his definition, the numbers $(a,b,c)$ are always $a\wedge b=0$, $a\wedge c=0$ and $b\wedge c=0$

$(a,b,c)$ represents points in 2D (complex numbers) with 3 coordinates which do not share any binary digit.

$(1,0,0)=1 \\
(0,1,0)=i \\
(0,0,1)=1+i$

I cannot simply take those 3 vectors as a basis, because it does not guarantees that the 3 components do not share any digit when written in binary.

$(a,b,0)$ are always points of a Sierpinski fractal and $\binom{a}{b}\mathrm{mod}\: 2=1$

$\binom{a}{b}$ is always odd when c=0

Does that algebra exists?

Comment: Is “bitwise and” meaningful for floats?

Comment: What is the bitwise and of two real numbers? For example, what is $-\sqrt{2} \wedge -\pi$?

Comment: Or you mean you want to restrict to integers?

Comment: @ rschwieb take the binary representation of a real number, like 101,11011

Comment: and negatives and positives?

Comment: @razivo  I would be happy with any convention. I hope to be able to adapt it to my needs if it doesn't works. At least I would have a clue on how to deal with the AND and complex arithmetic..

Comment: @ razivo  probably $-\| x \|\wedge-\| y \|=-(\| x \|\wedge\| y \|)$